# Instantiate class dynamically with locate

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection

I am trying to instantiate a class dynamically from a string that is fed to a method.

```
from pydoc import locate
name = "folder.subfolder.classname"
my_class = locate(name)
instance = my_class()
```

Doing this results in an error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My question is: how can I dinamically know which class I need to call? If I hardcode the value and do `my_class.classname()` I can instantiate it, but I want that last part to be dynamic, instead of hardcoded. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

This solution will gather all classes available in the module the user provides, and then simply instantiates the first class.

```
import inspect
from pydoc import locate
name = "folder.subfolder.classname"
my_module = locate(name)

all_classes = inspect.getmembers(my_module, inspect.isclass)
if len(all_classes) > 0:
    instance = all_classes[0][1]()
```

**Edit:**

Gathered from the comments I believe the following code will work for your use case:

```
from pydoc import locate
name = "folder.subfolder.classname"
my_module = locate(name)
class_name = name.rsplit('.')[-1]
my_class = getattr(my_module, class_name)
instance = my_class()
```

You do seem to be a bit confused as to what modules are which resulted in our miscommunication. class.py doesn't point to a class, but to a module. In that module (your class.py file) there can be multiple classes. For the answer above I just assume that in your class.py file you have a class with the same name as the file.

**Original Answer:**

Well as your error shows, your `my_class` variable is actually a module object. The name you provide doesn't actually point to your class but to the module containing the class.

To get a class from a module object by string you can do:

```
my_class = getattr(module, class_name)
```

and then like in your example code you can instantiate it like this:

```
instance = my_class()
```

To bring it all together:

```
module_name = "folder.subfolder.module_name"
my_module = locate(module_name)
my_class = getattr(my_module, class_name)
instance = my_class()
```

Comment: That is not an option Glenn. where is the variable class_name?

Comment: Could you provide more detail on this locate function that you call? Because it seems like your issue is simply the fact that you forget the module name. Instead of using `"folder.subfolder.classname"` you should try and use `"folder.subfolder.modulename.classname"`. The module name is the name of the python file without `.py`.

Comment: locate is from pydoc, I have added it to the question. the structure is "folder\subfolder\class.py" and I am trying to access the class with "folder.subfolder.class".

Comment: Thank you Glenn. I actually thought of that but was wondering if the module had some property that allowed me to get the name without string manipulation. That is my fallback, but I was looking for something more robust.

Comment: I have another solution you'll consider more robust, but it will still assume that there is just one class in the file, which in python normally isn't an assumption you are allowed to make. I'll edit my post.

Comment: my_class != my_class()

Answer (score 0):

You didn't locate the class inside of the file:

```py
from pydoc import locate
name = "folder.subfolder.filename.classname"
my_class = locate(name)
instance = my_class()
```